# Как сохранить декартово произведение в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Как можно из данного вида **[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]** получить **{1:[2,3], 2:[1,3], 3:[1,2]}**?
Нужно для реализации поиска в глубину графа, где чаще все используют словарь в качестве параметра функции. Всевозможные пары точек я создал с помощью `itertools.permutations`, но мне нужно сохранить все данные значения в `dict`. Из какой "точки" я могу попасть в другую, то есть, например, я могу из A попасть и в B, и в C. Следовательно в словаре должно появиться значение **A:[B,C]**

```
import itertools
n = int(input('Введите количество вершин '))
digits_for_dict = [x for x in range(1, n+1)]
lst = list(itertools.permutations([x for x in range(1,n+1)], 2))
d = dict.fromkeys(digits_for_dict, list)
print(lst)
```

Если использовать встроенный dict, то теряются все "значения".

```
n = int(input('Введите количество вершин '))
lst = dict(itertools.permutations([x for x in range(1,n+1)], 2))
print(lst)
```

> {1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2}

Со словарями вообще не работал, первый опыт....
Хочу взять код для поиска в глубину из данного видео: https://youtu.be/99AJrUyLvLQ

Comment: Да, я Вас не понял (удалил ответ)

Comment: Декартова произведения здесь не видно. Сомнительно что код нужно брать из видео, для этого есть книги и статьи. То, что вы хотите получить, по описанию похоже на списки достижимости, используются они редко (есть ещё матрица достижимости ). Что вы собираетесь с ними делать?

Comment: Ох, я уже запутался... Да, вы правы. Это не декартово произведение.... Туплю... Тут же перестановки по несколько элементов.... Делаю вообще для поиска в глубину (лабораторная работа 1 курс), там видео приложено сверху.

Comment: Вы определились, что вам нужно(дек.произв-е или перестановки)?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
d = {}
for i, j in lst:
    if i not in d.keys():
        d[i] = [j]
    else:
        d[i].append(j)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

itertools и zip помогут:

```py
from itertools import product, count

n = int(input('Введите количество вершин '))
d = {a: list(b) for a, b in zip(count(1), product(range(1,n+1), repeat=2))}
print(d)
```